# Variables in the Watson assistant

Tags: variables, ibm-watson, node-red

The Watson Assistant node on node red accepts as input a payload with a String, however in my chatbot, I had configured a variable "$user" to receive the username, but I am not able to assign a name to this variable.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: just to be clear. I send a message to the Watson node that I receive for example (payload: "hello") and Watson returns ("Hello $user"), but I'm not able to assign a value to this $user.

thank you for the time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that your dialog is outputting `Hello $user`.

For this to work `$user` needs to be set in the context. This is normally done by your dialog  when it has determined the name. When responding your dialog should check if the context `$user` is set.

See the service documentation - https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-runtime-context

Comment: This "hello $user" is configured in Watson Assistant. When I send a message and go through the wizard's node, it returns the content "hello " Without the variable that was defined there in Watson. If it did, I would be able to replace it with the username using node change, but that's not the case.

I wanted to know a way to name the variable that was defined in the Watson assistant.

I will take a look at the documentation again, Thank you very much.